# CNN how to optimize hyperparameters to prevent overfitting

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I am currently developing a CNN for multiclassification (3 classes) using Tensorflow Keras. I had used sklearn to split my data to 9:1 train/validation (1899 training data, 212 validation data).

[image]

My CNN model starts to increase slowly after 17 epochs. Is this means the CNN model starts overfitting? Any suggestion to decrease the validation loss as I had used dropout and batch normalization in the CNN model. I had also used EarlyStopping to investigate my CNN model but after some adjustment, my CNN model is still facing this problem.

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.1)

model = Sequential()

# filters, kernel size, input size
model.add(Conv2D(256, (3, 3), input_shape=X.shape[1:], padding='same'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=2))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))

model.add(Conv2D(256, (3, 3), padding='same'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=2))

model.add(Conv2D(256, (3, 3), padding='same'))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=2))

model.add(Conv2D(256, (3, 3), padding='same'))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=2))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(256))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Activation('relu'))

model.add(Dropout(0.8))
model.add(Dense(3))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))

tensorboard = TensorBoard(log_dir="CNN_Model_Rebuilt/logs/{}".format(NAME))

augmented_checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(
                'CNN_Model_Rebuilt/best model/normalization-best.h5',
                monitor='val_loss', verbose=0,
                save_best_only=True, mode='auto')

es = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss',
                   min_delta=0,
                   patience=20,
                   verbose=0, mode='auto')

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(X_train, to_categorical(y_train), batch_size=32, epochs=100,
                      validation_data=(X_test, to_categorical(y_test)), 
                      callbacks=[augmented_checkpoint, tensorboard, es], verbose=2)
```

Any advise/suggestion will be grateful. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To reduce overfitting you can try to **increase** the amount of Input Data then **augment** it (flip, rotate, scale, and etc.) this can improve generalization ability.

As for the model, some ideas you can try are to increase the **number of layers**, increase the **number of units**,  increase **drop-out value**,  use **different activation**, add a **new layer** that is not used, and some other built-in and customized **regularization** methods.

You can always play around these parameters and layers to achieve a **more accurate model** or **sometimes slightly worse**. The idea is tuning hyperparameters is mixing and matching.

You can also read about the TensorFlow Library Extension called **Tensor Flow Model Optimization Toolkit** in this [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/model_optimization).